# Mesh in edit mode not selectable by vertex select, and mesh is un-editable

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices

Ear mesh on the model's head appears darker and vertices arent showing in edit mode. I can still select the faces of the mesh but Cannot edit them when selected. All I can do is delete them I was working on the face when this happened and had the ears hidden with H after un-hiding them this happened.

[image: "Ear mesh on the model's head appears darker and vertices arent showing in edit mode. I can still select the faces of the mesh but Cannot edit them when selected. All I can do is delete them."]

Edit: I had to re-do the ears at this point with an older copy of the file I had made. Didn't set me back very far but I have encountered the problem again and I am too far in to use any backups as I have just noticed now and it happened to a bigger object. The same problem wherein vertex select mode I can not select vertices or see them.

[image: The whole head is supposed to be showing vertices like the ears as they are the same object]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that finds this. I have no clue how to replicate the bug but the vertices were just hidden without hiding the faces of the object. Try Alt + H when editing the object.

Edit: Forgot to mention I was thinking about this issue for a while and had tried Alt + H many times with it not working but every time I did that I had hidden the ears (Which were fine) beforehand. When it worked I had just entered edit mode.